# System tray Icon is not displaying after restart/logoff using NSIS

Tags: nsis

When I installed the application using NSIS it is showing the Notification Icon (System tray Icon). But once restart/logoff the icon is disappearing in the system tray.

While installing I am calling the "test.exe" that has the system tray functionality in the "Section". To display the system tray functionality even after restart/logoff, Do we need to add this functionality in any other place?

Below is my existing code that is displaying the system tray once installation has completed:

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification icons (system tray icons) only exist while their application is running. If you want the icon to persist after a reboot then you must arrange for the application to start when the user logs in.

You can add a value to [the run key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys):

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "MyApplication" '"$InstDir\MyApp.exe"' ; Can also be created in HKCU
```

or a startup shortcut:

```
CreateShortcut "$SMStartup\MyApp.lnk" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
```

Comment: The first argument can't be empty! You don't start services like that. If it is set to automatic then it will start if you have a correctly written NT service.

Comment: These questions have nothing to do with NSIS. Did you write Display.exe?

Comment: If Display.exe is failing to start another process then you need to look for the error code (GetLastError()) from CreateProcess/ShellExecuteEx...

Comment: I doubt that is the correct error but you should ask a separate question, this has nothing to do with NSIS.

Comment: Your app needs to create the icon again when it gets the special message from the taskbar, this has nothing to do with NSIS.

Comment: I don't think startup shortcuts are allowed to request elevation because the user would get a UAC dialog every time they log in.

Comment: Talking about your systray application behavior is pointless because we have no clue what it is nor how it works.